# Issues with tabbar / tabbarview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, uitabbarcontroller

I have a page which i want to separate in 3 different 'pages' using the tabbar.
When i want to add other stuff to these pages (for example some text on top of my ListView.builder the contents of my listview.builder are gone.

My homepage is also responsible for my appbar and bottombar, this groceries page is the 3rd index of my bottom bar.

Im not really that experienced yet, im having some issues with my page buildup.
Below is the code for my groceries page where all other stuff dissapear if i wrap my listview.builder in a column for example so i can add a title for example on top of the listview.builder results. Since my homepage is responsible for my appbar i do not want that to be regenerated on every page, only the title changes when switching

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: const [
                Tab(
                  text: ('Shopping list'),
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: ('Menus'),
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: ('Grocery Stores'),
                )
              ]),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: shoppingListItem.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ShoppingItemTile(
                        text: shoppingListItem[index].title);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: menuItem.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return MenuItemTile(text: menuItem[index].menuName[0]);
                  },
                  //const Text('My Menus'),
                ),
              ),
              const Text('My Grocery Stores')
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

I have tried wrapping my Listview.builder in other widgets. All have the same result (listview.builder contents gone).

Comment: do you get any error message

Comment: No, no error messages, the contents of the listview builder are gone when i wrap it in any other widget

Comment: It is possible the error is coming from `ShoppingItemTile` which didn't include on question.

Answer (score 0):

Issue gas been solved by a complete redesign if my page. Tnx for thinking with me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).